Nested serializer names disappear in drf-spectacular swagger-ui schema view when read_only or allow_null is set?
I am using the drf-spectacular library together with Swagger-UI to document my Django Rest serializers (schemas).
What I have noticed is that if I set the read_only=True or allow_null=True attribute of any nested serializer fields, the name of that nested serializer disappears from the schema view in Swagger-UI. If I remove those attributes or set them to False, the names re-appear. Not sure why this is happening?
class MySerializerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    read_only_field = MyReadOnlySerializerSerializer(read_only=True) #--> 'MyReadOnlySerializer' name is not shown
    null_field = MyNullSerializerSerializer(read_only=False, allow_null=True) #--> 'MyNullSerializer' name is not shown
    normal_field = MyOtherSerializerSerializer(read_only=False) #--> 'MyOtherSerializer" name is shown



you have to override the function named get_component_name in your serializer and used in your view.

@Tanveer can you be more specific where to override this function ? I did try it but it didn't make any difference. The name also appears fine as long as those parameters are not being set, so it's not as if the name isn't there.
